# Is there any Rails function to check if a partial exists?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partial

When I render a partial which does not exists, I get an Exception. I'd like to check if a partial exists before rendering it and in case it doesn't exist, I'll render something else. I did the following code in my .erb file, but I think there should be a better way to do this:

```
    <% begin %>
      <%= render :partial => "#{dynamic_partial}" %>
    <% rescue ActionView::MissingTemplate %>
      Can't show this data!
    <% end %>
```

Comment: The answer that uses `rescue` is risky. I would look at the other solutions before using it.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

Currently, I'm using the following in my Rails 3/3.1 projects:

```
lookup_context.find_all('posts/_form').any?
```

The advantage over other solutions I've seen is that this will look in all view paths instead of just your rails root. This is important to me as I have a lot of rails engines.

This also works in Rails 4.

Comment: lookup_context.exists?('posts/find') didn't work for me. Instead I used lookup_context.exists?(name, prefix, partial) or lookup_content.exists?('find', 'posts', true) in this example.

Comment: This is the current (rails >= 3.2) way to check for templates (source [apidock](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/LookupContext/ViewPaths/template_exists%3F))

Comment: If the partial is in the same folder as the current view template, you can use `lookup_context.exists?("find", lookup_context.prefixes, true)`. This way, you don't need to hard-code the view directory into the call. Note, this is for partials. For non-partials, omit the last arg (or use false instead of true)

Answer (score 75):

I was struggling with this too.  This is the method I ended up using:

```
<%= render :partial => "#{dynamic_partial}" rescue nil %>
```

Basically, if the partial doesn't exist, do nothing.  Did you want to print something if the partial is missing, though?

**Edit 1:** Oh, I fail at reading comprehension.  You did say that you wanted to render something else.  In that case, how about this?

```
<%= render :partial => "#{dynamic_partial}" rescue render :partial => 'partial_that_actually_exists' %>
```

or

```
<%= render :partial => "#{dynamic_partial}" rescue "Can't show this data!" %>
```

**Edit 2:**

Alternative: Checking for existence of the partial file:

```
<%= render :partial => "#{dynamic_partial}" if File.exists?(Rails.root.join("app", "views", params[:controller], "_#{dynamic_partial}.html.erb")) %>
```

Comment: My question is that I don't want to use Exceptions to do the flow control, which is a anti-pattern: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546514/java-exceptions-as-control-flow

Comment: An exception is a type of flow control used to handle things that happen beyond a program's normal operation.  If the dynamic partial is supposed to be there but something goes wrong and it ends up not being there, then that is a reasonable use for an exception (IMO, of course - proper use of exceptions is a holy war itself).  I would say your alternative is to check the filesystem for whether or not the actual file exists.  I'll update my answer with that code.

Comment: I like the solution, nevertheless it swallows any kind of exception thrown in the partial. IMHO this makes it harder to track down errors.

Comment: If you have a different type of exception, the `rescue nil` and `... rescue ...` methods will hide it. That leads to bugs that are hard to debug.

Comment: I really dislike this solution. rescuing is expensive, and File.exists? assumes that the partial can only be in one location. @Rein's solution using the lookup_context is the way to go I believe.

Comment: Yes, LookupContext should be used in Rails 3.  Keep in mind this question is from the era of 2.3.x.

Answer (score 55):

From inside a view, template_exists? works, but the calling convention doesn't work with the single partial name string, instead it takes template_exists?(name, prefix, partial)

To check for partial on path:
   app/views/posts/_form.html.slim

Use:

```
lookup_context.template_exists?("form", "posts", true)
```

Comment: On Rails 3.0.10 I found that if I have an alternate extension, like app/views/posts/_foo.txt.erb, I needed to add that to the argument as:  template_exists?("foo.txt", "posts", true)

Comment: This is deprecated in rails 3.2

Comment: It does not appear to be delegated in Rails 3.2.x, however, the second argument is an array of prefixes. Further, it exists on the current controller.

Comment: You can use lookup_context.prefixes as the second argument: lookup_context.template_exists?("form", lookup_context.prefixes, true)

Comment: This is the better answer in terms of accessing this information from the view layer.

Answer (score 31):

In Rails 3.2.13, if you're in a controller, you can use this :

```
template_exists?("#{dynamic_partial}", _prefixes, true)
```

`template_exists?` is delegated to `lookupcontext`, as you can see in [`AbstractController::ViewPaths`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.2.13/actionpack/lib/abstract_controller/view_paths.rb#L13-L14)

`_prefixes` gives the context of the controller's inheritance chain.

`true` because you're looking for a partial (you can omit this argument if you want a regular template).

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/LookupContext/ViewPaths.html#method-i-template_exists-3F

Comment: Upvoted. More up-to-date and better explanation of parameters.

Comment: From a view (such as a layout), this works: `lookup_context.template_exists?("navbar", controller._prefixes, :partial)`. This tells me if the current template rendering this layout has the stated "navbar" partial, and if so I can render it. I pass `:partial` just to be explicit about what that boolean is -- `:partial` is truthy. Thanks for the `_prefixes` bit, @Flackou!

Comment: Replace `_prefixes` with `nil` if you're calling a partial that's in a different parent directory.

Answer (score 8):

I know this has been answered and is a million years old, but here's how i ended up fixing this for me...

Rails 4.2

First, i put this in my application_helper.rb

```
  def render_if_exists(path_to_partial)
    render path_to_partial if lookup_context.find_all(path_to_partial,[],true).any?
  end
```

and now instead of calling

`<%= render "#{dynamic_path}" if lookup_context.find_all("#{dynamic_path}",[],true).any? %>`

i just call `<%= render_if_exists "#{dynamic_path}" %>`

hope that helps. (haven't tried in rails3)

Comment: This doesn't work if you want to provide a fallback.
It also doesn't take local variables into consideration.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Very clean answer.

Comment: @BenPolinsky I suppose you can use `def render_if_exists(*args); render(*args) if ...` for that

Answer (score 8):

I have used this paradigm on many occasions with great success:

```
<%=
  begin
    render partial: "#{dynamic_partial}"
  rescue ActionView::MissingTemplate
    # handle the specific case of the partial being missing
  rescue
    # handle any other exception raised while rendering the partial
  end
%>
```

The benefit of the code above is that we can handle tow specific cases:

- The partial is indeed missing
- The partial exists, but it threw an error for some reason

If we just use the code `<%= render :partial => "#{dynamic_partial}" rescue nil %>` or some derivative, the partial may exist but raise an exception which will be silently eaten and become a source of pain to debug.

Answer (score 8):

What about your own helper:

```
def render_if_exists(path, *args)
  render path, *args
rescue ActionView::MissingTemplate
  nil
end
```

Answer (score 4):

This works for me in Rails 6.1:

```
<% if lookup_context.exists?("override_partial", ['path/after/app/views'], true) %>
  <%= render partial: "path/after/app/views/override_partial" %>
<% else %>
  <%= render partial: "default_partial" %>
<% end %>
```

Here I have my partial nested some levels deeper than normal (`app/views/path/after/app/views/_override_partial`) so that's why I'm adding it as the prefixes array, but you can use `lookup_context.prefixes` instead if you don't need it.

I could have also used `prepend_view_path` on the controller. It's up to you :)

Comment: Also works inside a controller method. Thanks!