# Not able to continue when an Assert condition fails in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, assert

I want execution to be continue till end when Assert condition is failing in Selenium WebDriver Script. In my code, when `Assert` condition fails, it is stopping executing the rest of the code.

Here is code what I wrote. Need help.

```
try
{
    Assert.assertEquals(false, status);
}
catch(Exception Ex)
{
    System.out.println("Disabled user can register for workshop : case Failed ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [exceptions to control the flow of logic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1546525) through code is considered bad practice (you are catching the exception, writing an error message, and continuing processing).

Instead of using `assertEquals`, you could check the condition directly:

```
if (status == false) {
    System.out.println("Disabled user can register for workshop : case Failed ");
}
```

Also, if you still want to print additional information when a test fails (and halt further checks in the test), the `Asserts` usually provide an overload for optional last parameter to convey such information when the test fails:

```
Assert.assertEquals(false, status, 
 "Disabled user can register for workshop : case Failed ");
```

Answer (score 0):

JUnit has a rule called *ErrorCollector* that can be used to gather progressive stats about a test and report at the end of the execution.

> Don't combine Assert and ErrorCollector, you will lose ErrorCollector information if your test fails from an Assert
>
> At the end of your test any failures will be gathered and listed collectively in the JUnit output.

```
package stackoverflow.proof.junit;

import org.hamcrest.core.Is;
import org.hamcrest.core.IsEqual;
import org.hamcrest.core.IsNull;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.rules.ErrorCollector;

/**
 * Test case for demonstrating some Junit Rule behaviors.
 * <p/>
 * Requires at least JUnit 4.7
 * 
 * @see "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33183789/not-able-to-continue-when-an-assert-condition-fails-in-selenium-webdriver/33183882#33183882"
 * @author http://stackoverflow.com/users/5407189/jeremiah
 * @since Oct 17, 2015
 *
 */
public class JUnitRulesDemoTest {
    /**
     * Collector which can be used to track problems through an event series and still allow a test to run to
     * completion.
     */
    @Rule
    public ErrorCollector collector = new ErrorCollector();

    /**
     * Test illustrating ErrorCollector behavior.
     * 
     */
    @Test
    public void testErrorCollector() {
        collector.checkThat("These things don't match", new Object(), IsEqual.equalTo(new Object()));
        collector.checkThat(new Object(), IsNull.notNullValue());
        try {
            throw new Exception("Demonstration Exception in collector");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            collector.addError(ex);
        }
        collector.checkThat("Status does not match!", true, Is.is(true));
        System.out.println("Done.");
    }
    
    /**
     * Test illustrating ErrorCollector behavior when an Assert Fails the Test.
     * 
     */
    @Test
    public void testErrorCollectorWithAssert() {
        collector.checkThat("These things don't match", new Object(), IsEqual.equalTo(new Object()));
        collector.checkThat(new Object(), IsNull.notNullValue());
        try {
            throw new Exception("Demonstration Exception in collector");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            collector.addError(ex);
        }
        //Test stops here.  You won't see "done", nor will you see any of the previous ErrorCollector status'
        Assert.assertTrue(false);
        
        collector.checkThat("Status does not match!", true, Is.is(true));
        System.out.println("Done.");
    }

}
```

[image: JUnit Result]

A Rule must:

- Be annotated with *@Rule*
- Be declared **public** in your test.

---

**Proposed Solution:**

In the case you list above you should remove the try/catch block and use the *Is* Matcher instead of *org.junit.Assert.assertEquals*:

```
@Rule
public ErrorCollector collector = new ErrorCollector();

@Test
public void testSomething() {
  boolean status = doStatusEval(); 
  collector.checkThat("Disabled user can register for workshop", false, Is.is(status));
 //Continue adding things to the collector.
}
```

Best of Luck!

Comment: In the Junit screenshot I should point out that the two junit tests were run in the same session.  The proof of *testErrorCollectorWithAssert* is called out in the console where you only see one 'Done' statement for both tests.  Only one of them completed.