# Inventory Program Java Help Needed

Tags: java, arrays, class, object

I am making an inventory program in java, I need to getItem from the index. I am a bit confused how to return the item from the index.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are you trying to get it from an array or an actual ArrayList? What does your code look like?

Comment: @Orin2005 *"What does your code look like?"* See the edit history. OP posted the code, but removed it later.

Answer (score 1):

This is the easiest method yet! If you simply want to retrieve the item by position, then [`ArrayList#get`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get(int)) is your method. Per the Oracle docs,

> Returns the element at the specified position in this list.

```
public StockItem getItem(int index) {
    return this.stock.get(index);
}
```

However, you have to add in the special case for the `null` return specified by your JavaDocs. There are two ways to do this

### First way

```
public StockItem getItem(int index) {
    if (index < 0 || index >= this.stock.size()){
        return null;
    }
    return this.stock.get(index);
}
```

### Second way

```
public StockItem getItem(int index) {
    try{
        return this.stock.get(index);
    }catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException e){
        return null;
    }
}
```

I'd suggest the first way because, although there is additional logic, using `Exception`s as regular control flow in your code is not good practice. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546514/java-exceptions-as-control-flow) and [this](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/189222/are-exceptions-as-control-flow-considered-a-serious-antipattern-if-so-why) for more discussion.

Comment: how should I return null if the index is not valid? Should I add else return null?

Comment: @latif.daniya Updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

```
public StockItem getItem(int index) {
     try
     {
         return stock.get(index)
     }
     catch(IndexOutOfBoundsException ex)
     {
         return null;
     }
}
```

Comment: Exceptions should not be used like this, you should check that the index is valid instead.