# How to keep inserting rows after BatchUpdateException caused by primary key violation?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, primary-key

This is probably very silly to ask, but I'm facing this situation:

I have a table that I'm populating every time a user sends a request, I'm using the date on one the fields (a date) from the last row I inserted. The problem is, the last row I inserted is always going to try and insert itself because it is in the range I'm considering. I know a solution is probably just adding a minute or two to the last row, but from this my question comes.
How can I in java, using a PreparedStatement and a batch to insert multiple rows, skip the ones that send me that PRIMARY_KEY_VIOLATION exception, and keep inserting the ones that are ok?
I mean, for instance, I have in my table a row "runner" with the value 25, and that's my primary key, and then I want to insert these rows: 
(25,26,27)
The 25 values cannot be inserted, so I want to catch the exception and do something to keep inserting the 26 and 27 values.
Is it possible?

I appreciate your help and comments. Thank you in advance!

Comment: See the `BatchUpdateException` API.  What you're suggesting _might_ be  possible but will be horribly ugly.  Avoid the PK violation.  Create a sequence so you can "INSERT INTO TABLE T SELECT MYSEQUENCE.NEXTVAL, OTHER_FIELD1, OHTER_FIELD2 WHERE ...

Comment: @AndrewS - Using a sequence does not solve the problem. Sure it generates a unique value but you have just inserted a duplicate record with a meaningless technical key.

Comment: The question is, why are you selecting an already inserted row? Surely the problem you need to fix is getting a valid data source rather than handling exceptions in the data target.

Comment: JDBC driver implementations can choose to stop on error or continue batch execution on error, but drivers must consistently use the same handling. Oracle chose to bail on error; there is no way to change this.

Answer (score 0):

It's not fully clear to me what you're trying to achieve. A db schema, code and an example might help. But from what I understand, I have the following hints:

- Think about your **primary key**

  - A *technical key* should be unique **without any programming** (like trial & error...). A timestamp usually does not satisfy that criteria. The *sequence datatype* of your database or a *GUID* is a good bet as they're intended for that use.
  - A *non-techical key* should represent **the whole row** and **only** the specific row. A date/timestamp might be an acceptable key to represent a day in a calendar application or a specific instance in time. A timestamp usually does not represent a "user request".
- **Think in transactions**: Databases generally emphasize *atomic, transactional* operations. If a part of an operations fails, you have to rollback the **whole transaction**.
  As AndrewS points out, continuing your batch processing after a `BatchUpdateException` might be possible (depending on the driver) but that's definitely **not a good practice**. It's a code smell that indicates you're doing something wrong the first place.
- **Avoid exceptions**: Using Exceptions for control flow is also considered a code smell (see e.g. [Java: Exceptions as control flow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546514/java-exceptions-as-control-flow#1546525) with reference to Item 57 in Joshua Bloch's "Effective Java"). Checking for conditions that lead to an exception before trying an operation is usually preferred. Or as APC points out: if you know your code returns the last row you inserted, why don't you just leave this out of your insert statement?