# Replace Recursion with Iteration using Explicit Stack

Tags: recursion, stack

In a recursive function call it is all about a implicit stack maintenance, so is it possible to replace all the recursive functions with an iterative one using a stack explicitly?

Comment: Are you asking if Lisp can be implemented in low-level language?

Comment: @ John Coleman no i'm asking for a generalized way.

Comment: the point of my tangential comment was that the answer is *obviously* yes because languages like Lisp are routinely implemented in low-level languages which lack recursion. Recursion is a higher-order abstraction which is in practice almost always implemented in terms of lower level abstractions (such as stacks) which are themselves implemented in terms of even lower level abstractions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Of course it will be slower then using "real" stack but I can think of two advantages:
- code isn't constrained by native stack size
- it is easy to break from recursion if it was just used to search for value ( compare with [breaking out of a recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856124/breaking-out-of-a-recursion-in-java)  )

Here is a nice example of [using explicit stack instead of recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/159692/158037)